# Running a Node.js script using a bash command in Airflow and Docker

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, airflow

I'm trying to schedule some node.js scripts using Airflow.

I've managed to successfully set up Airflow in a Docker container using the puckel Airflow image (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow), and have gotten a sample HelloWorld DAG to work using this setup.

At the moment, I'm setting up each task in the DAG to run a separate node.js script using the below format:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
     task_id = "runNodeJsScript"
     bash_command = "/path/to/node/modules/on/virtual/machine  /path/to/external/nodejs/script/on/virtual/machine"
     dag = dag
)
```

But when I test out the tasks using the "Airflow test" method, I get the error "Bash Command Failed."

Is there something missing in the above code? Do I need to add something like #!/bin/bash to the command or the node.js script to get it to work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you do NOT need *shebang* `#!/bin.bash` for running single bash-command (it is needed for running entire scripts). What is the *executor* that you are using (`LocalExecutor` / `CeleryExecutor`)? Based on that, you'll have to make `node.js` runtime available in the environment where bash-command is being triggered

Comment: I'm using the default SequentialExecutor. Do you think it would be better to switch to the LocalExecutor? At the moment, I've got node.js installed on the virtual machine I've set up Docker/Airflow on.

Comment: **[1]** switch to `LocalExecutor` as `SequentialExecutor` wouldn't let you even test / mimic multiple concurrent tasks **[2]** `"..I've got node.js installed on the virtual machine I've set up Docker/Airflow on.."` this is not enough / not of any use. `pukel/docker-airflow` sets up the environment so that anything you run on Airflow runs within it's `docker` containers. So you must modify either the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/Dockerfile) or [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh) to install `node.js`

Comment: Thanks! I'll switch to LocalExecutor like you suggested, and modify the Dockerfile as well to install node.js. If puckel/docker-airflow sets up the environment to run everything through docker containers, do I need to move the node.js scripts into the Airflow container as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to put your `node.js` scripts into the volume that is mounted in the container as [defined in `docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml`](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml#L26)

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that the node.js scripts go into the same volume as the DAGs _./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags_? The reason I ask is that I initially set Docker and Airflow up to include the scripts in the same volume, and the container kept crashing each time.